# which node modules is my nwjs app using?

Tags: node-modules, nwjs

I have a lot of modules in the node_modules folder of my nwjs app. I want to know which ones are not used (anymore) by my app so I can uninstall them.

I suspect I haven't always added  --save or --save-dev to the npm install command.

How can I find out which ones are used by nwjs and which ones I added without using  --save?

Comment: Delete the contents of the node_modules folder. Then run nom install. Then run your app. The missing dependencies (one's you've not use --save or --save-dev) will cause the app to error.

Comment: As a side note, if you have the flexibility, consider using Yarn: https://yarnpkg.com/en/